# How do I pass collection results to a view?

Tags: php, laravel

I have JSON data that I filtered using Laravel collection and assigned the results to the $results variable which works fine. My issue comes in when I try passing the $results to the view using the code below.

```
    $collection = collect($pc);
    $results = $collection->whereIn('transaction_account', $quotation_title);
    $results->all();       
    return view('admin.payments',['$results'=>$results]);
```

I get undefined variable: results error in view.

Undefined variable: results (View: /home1/hotelsto/partners.hotelstore.co.ke/resources/views/admin/payments.blade.php)

How do I correctly pass the results to the view?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to change it to this :

```
return view('admin.payments',['results'=>$results]);
```

You don't need the dollar sign there.

Answer (score 2):

you are trying to assign `$results` to a key as `$results`.

Try changing it to:

```php
return view('admin.payments',['results'=>$results]);
```

Or the clean way:

```php
$collection = collect($pc);
$results = $collection->whereIn('transaction_account', $quotation_title)->all();

return view('admin.payments', compact('results'));
```

Read about [compact()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.compact.php)

Answer (score 0):

typo at the end. not `['$results'=>$results]);` but `['results'=>$results]);`

```
$collection = collect($pc);
$results = $collection->whereIn('transaction_account', $quotation_title);
$results->all();       
return view('admin.payments',['results'=>$results]);
```